# Why does executable script behave differently from when its commands are run manually?

Tags: bash, scripts, ssh

I am trying to add a private key to my sshagent. Running the commands

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
```

does the job just fine so that when I run `ssh-add -l`, I see the key has been added. This is also the case even without running the `eval` command at all (which perhaps begs the question why I would need to run it). However, if I instead create an executable file `add_key.sh` (using the shebang and `chmod +x`) and add those exact commands to it and then run it, `ssh-add -l` does not show the key and instead shows `"The agent has no identities"`.

If I comment out the `eval` command in the script and run it, there is no problem and it properly adds the key to the agent. What is it about my script that causes `ssh-add` to fail adding the key, and why is that not a problem if I comment out the `eval` command from the script or just run the commands manually?

Comment: Try `echo "$(ssh-agent -s)";echo $SHELL`. Do you clear out your key space prior to testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssh-agent -s` starts a *new* agent; when you `eval` its output, you change the shell environment so that the following `ssh-add` adds the identity to **that** agent.

If you do that in a script, then when you return to the parent environment the new values of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` / `SSH_AGENT_PID` are lost, so (although the new agent is still running), `ssh-add -l` can't connect to it.

When you just run `ssh-agent -s` *without* `eval`, it starts a new agent but just prints the new environment to standard output, so `ssh-add` adds the new identity to whatever agent was already running in the parent environment.